# Need to create csv file in cpanel directory from html table in Javascript code

Tags: javascript

I can download csv file from html table with the help of the following javascript code;

```
function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
var csvFile;
var downloadLink;

// CSV file
csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

// Download link
downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

// File name
downloadLink.download = filename;

// Create a link to the file
downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

// Hide download link
downloadLink.style.display = "none";

// Add the link to DOM
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

// Click download link
downloadLink.click();
}

function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
var csv = [];
var rows = document.querySelectorAll(".csv");

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
var row = []; 

cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll(".csvs");
            // cols =   cols.replace(",","");

for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) 
row.push(cols[j].innerText.replace(",",""));

csv.push(row.join(","));        
}

// Download CSV file //// now need to create file in cpanel dir.
downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
}
```

Now need to create csv file in cpanel directory but not download .Kindly change the same code so that I use it with small change of creation of csv file.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow. Please could you share what you have already tried? We are here to help you with issues, not write code for you.

Comment: I have written code above for downloading csv file now just need to create. I dont have code yet.

Comment: Well, people aren't going to code something for you. The best thing to do would be to go away and try it yourself and if you run in to an issue come back and people would be more than willing to help.

Comment: I rather have my doubts that you’ve written that code yourself … If you did, I would assume you’d know that this is client-side JavaScript, and that that can not write any files directly on the server.

Comment: @misorude Yes you are right. I just got the code and it works for downloading.. and now I got it that JS not server-side language so it would not upload.. but I got alternative way. thanks

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a client-side language so it can not perform any function that is concerned with server so need PHP script to do so.